# How to get websocket over SSL in Express app?

Tags: node.js, express, ssl, websocket

After making my websocket work localy i deployed it and got security errors due to it not being over SSL. I am hosting a NodeJS Express app with Nginx and Certbot.

server.js

```js
const express = require('express');
const app     = express();

// unrelated imports

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(cors());
app.use(express.static('public'));
app.use(bodyParser.json({ limit: '50mb' }))

require('./services/socket')(app)

// unrelated endpoints

app.listen(port);
```

socket.js

```js
let WebSocket = require('ws');

module.exports = function(app) {

    let ws_server = new WebSocket.Server();

    ws_server.on('connection', (connection) => {

        connection.on('message', (message) => {
            ws_server.clients.forEach((client) => {
                if (client.readyState === WebSocket.OPEN && client != connection) {
                    client.send(message);
                }
            });
        });
    });
}
```

Now the app is HTTPS but not the websocket, how can i get the socket to also use SSL/certs?

Comment: If you are using nginx you can do all ssl there and use plain http on the node side.

Comment: @Teivaz Could you expand on this? That is what i am currently doing but my socket does not accept `wss://`.

Answer (score 0):

In such setup nginx needs to handle the SSL and be properly set up to work with web sockets. Here's an article from nginx blog [NGINX as a WebSocket Proxy](https://www.nginx.com/blog/websocket-nginx/) . The essential bits are:

```
location /wsapp/ {
    proxy_pass http://wsbackend;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
}
```

You might also want to set up timeouts for the connection.

And Express needs to trust the reverse proxy. Here's an article from them [Express behind proxies](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/behind-proxies.html)
. If you are deploying in a secure environment you can just set it to `app.set('trust proxy', ()=>true)`

---

For reference here are the nginx timeouts I had to set up for my application:

```
    proxy_connect_timeout 14d;
    proxy_read_timeout 14d;
    proxy_send_timeout 14d;
```